# bash scripting - function outputs results to empty file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a function that reads a list of names and uses that as input into another command like so:

```
runMain() {
    getName=$(PGPASSWORD=$_clpw1 psql -h myendpoint.com -U ops_readonly -d dev -p 5439 -t -c "select datname from pg_database where datname not like 'template%' and datname not like 'tealium%' and datname not like 'padb%' and datname not like 'services%' and datname not like 'sales%' and datname not like 'dev%' and datname not like 'demo_%' and datname not like '%_demo' and datname not like 'nt_%';")
    echo "${getName}" >> "${_file}"
    for db in $(cat "${_file}");
        do
           getSchema=$(PGPASSWORD=$_clpw2 psql -h myendpoint.com -U masteruser -d  "${db}" -p 5439 -t -c "select distinct 'GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ' || table_schema ||' TO ops_readonly;' FROM information_schema.tables where table_catalog='%${db}%' and table_schema not in ('pg_catalog','information_schema');") 
           echo "${getSchema}" >> "${_script}"
        done
}
```

I do an `echo "${getSchema}" >> "${_script}"` so I can output my query findings to a file.

I can see the output file has been touched and its like 32k, however the file its **empty**.

I've tested the command line string separately and it works and i'm getting the output I expect.

Is there a better way to capture the output to a file? What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Needs more [mcve]. Also, a file cannot be both "like 32k" and "empty".

Comment: add a echo $db inside the for loop and also  echo "${getSchema}" and check what they print.

Comment: See [Why you don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) -- and use `set -x` to enable tracing and reproduce your problem with it enabled.

Comment: @AbhijitPritam, `echo $db` is actually often misleading. Much better to encourage `declare -p db` and/or `declare -p getSchema`. See the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) for history of why its behavior is underspecified and hard to predict.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy – I assume that the content of `$_file` is just host names, which will only contain dots, dashes, and alphanumerics, so the use of `for` here should be fine. The file may even be space-delimited, in which case your suggestion of using `while IFS= read -r db` would yield a different result. I also find it interesting that you suggest `declare -p db` over `printf %s "$db\n"` which is more portable and closer to the intention.

Comment: the contents of `$_file` is just database names. All strings - `abc def ghi`

Comment: Rather than capturing output to variables and then `echo`ing that to a file, why not just redirect output directly to the file? e.g. use `PGPASSWORD=$_clpw1 psql ... >> "${_file}"` instead of `getName=$(PGPASSWORD=$_clpw1 psql ...); echo "$getName" >> "${_file}"`. It's simpler and there're fewer things that can go wrong.

Comment: thank you all for chiming in and best practice. Now that I figure out the root cause, I will take in to account your suggestions for improvement. I appreciate it.

Comment: @AdamKatz, assuming that data will be what you expect is dangerous. My favorite story on the subject involves a major data loss event after a bug in a C library used by a Python program generating a filename happened to dump a bunch of random content into a buffer that contained a `*` surrounded by whitespace... which resulted in a cleanup script deleting the entire backup store of data used to drive customer billing. Point being that it only takes one sufficiently expensive mistake to justify getting the habit of programming defensively even when you think errors "can't" happen.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy – Sure, that's controllable w/out the while loop; see my changes to my answer, which uses `grep -o` to avoid non-host characters. The `while` loop in the link you provided earlier would work as well, though I think `IFS` needs to be modified to allow spaces.

Comment: @AdamKatz, sure, but once you get in the code of using code in a teaching resource that's only safe when used in the context of other specific surrounding code, you want to be *really* careful in the comments to prevent folks from copy-and-pasting / reusing examples you showcased in a different context where they're unsafe. Or, of course, you could just stick to practices where such warnings are unneeded altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is empty (filled with 32k of blank lines) because `${getName}` and `${getSchema}` are both empty. Therefore, the problem is in those `psql` commands.

It's okay to put one level of double quotes inside a `"$(…)"` (never mind that SO's highlighting messes it up), so you can do this:

```
runMain() {
    getName="$(PGPASSWORD="$_clpw1" psql -h myendpoint.com -U ops_readonly -d dev -p 5439 -t -c "select datname from pg_database where datname not like 'template%' and datname not like 'tealium%' and datname not like 'padb%' and datname not like 'services%' and datname not like 'sales%' and datname not like 'dev%' and datname not like 'demo_%' and datname not like '%_demo' and datname not like 'nt_%';" 2>&1)"
    echo "${getName}" >> "${_file}"
    for db in $(grep -o '[[:alnum:].-][[:alnum:].-]*' "${_file}");
        do
           getSchema="$(PGPASSWORD="$_clpw2" psql -h myendpoint.com -U masteruser -d  "${db}" -p 5439 -t -c "select distinct 'GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ' || table_schema ||' TO ops_readonly;' FROM information_schema.tables where table_catalog='%${db}%' and table_schema not in ('pg_catalog','information_schema');" 2>&1)" 
           echo "${getSchema}" >> "${_script}"
        done
}
```

In addition to quoting your command substitution, I also quoted your passwords (which matters tremendously if you have spaces or other non-word characters in them!).  Finally, I gave your commands `2>&1` to convert standard error into standard output so it can be captured in your output files, which might reveal other problems (like a bad password or bad connection).

The grep command makes the for loop safe to execute, ensuring the inputs are restricted to one or more alphanumeric characters, dots, and hyphens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm testing it right now, and still experiencing same type of results. Focusing on the `psql` command.

Answer (score 0):

An output file was created. I was just getting 0 results. The root of my issue was in the plsql query. Running it via command line, my use of `'%${db}%'` is valid if running queries for postgres using `like` and since I am not using `like`, removing the surrounding `%` to `'${db}'` produced my output.